# LocalDB changes persist in different mdf files - Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, localdb

I am trying to rebuild an application that originally used sqlite to now use 'localdb'.  (I want an application that can create its own database locally and at runtime without requiring a pre-installed instance of sql server or sql express on the target machine)

I want to move away from using a 'third party' library (sqlite) as experience has told me it can be a pain to get it working from scratch, and towards something supposedly more straightforward to get up and running from scratch.

Using code copied (and slightly modified) from the web I have managed to create an mdf file dynamically/programmatically,  but I am puzzled by what happens if I run it more than once,  even if I choose a new filename each time.  Namely it seems to somehow keep the changes/additions made on each run.  Below is the relevant code...

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn;

        public  void CreateSqlDatabase(string filename)
        {
            string databaseName = 
            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
            conn = new SqlConnection(
              String.Format(

 @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"

              ));
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = 
                 String.Format(

 "CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME={0}, FILENAME='{1}')"

                 , databaseName, filename);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.CommandText = 

 String.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", databaseName);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                CreateSqlDatabase(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = 

 "create table mytable (id int, name nvarchar(100))";

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.CommandText = 

 "insert into mytable (id,name) values (10,'testing')";

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.CommandText = "select * from mytable";
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text += 

 reader["id"].ToString() + ", " + reader["name"].ToString() + "\r\n";

            }
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

If I run the app once It runs through fine.

If I run the app a second time, and choose a different filename for the database it tells me 'mytable' already exists.

If I comment out the create table code it runs, but the select query returns multiple rows indicating multiple inserts (one for each time the app runs)

I am just seeking to understand why this happens.  Do I need to delete database/table each time if I want the app to behave as if it has created the database/table from scratch on each subsequent run?

Comment: It seem that you always connected to the master database and not the one you created. So when you create the table, it created within the master db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initial catalog 'master' in your connection string. Are you sure you haven't created the tables in the master database instead of the newly created database?

After the creation & detach of the database file, you could try and change your connection to:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=c:\xxx\xxx\xxx.mdf");
```

Comment: That was copied word-for-word from another stack overflow question.  Does 'master' exist somewhere other than the file?  Somewhere else on the system?  Forgive the naive question.

Comment: The 'master' database in sqlserver is a system database containing information about registered databases, backups, query executions, ...

Comment: I see.  If I change it from 'master' to the name specified for the database it then gives me an error about login failure.  I guess it *was* easier and less pain-in-the-ass to use sqlite.

Comment: @MrVimes I'd suggest to you that, depending on what you're doing, LocalDB is going to be well worth the (very) slight additional effort to get it working properly, vs SQLite.  The feature sets are worlds apart.

Comment: As you suggested I re-attached with the filename specified in the connection string, and the application is now behaving more as expected,  and I understand better what was happening.  Thankyou codemonkey

Comment: @dodexahedron thanks.  It was less additional effort than I expected, and codemonkey's question edit provided the code (and understanding) I needed.  Thankyou for your helps :)